vs code debugger is not recognizing any breakpoints, nor is it logging any console.log messages
My vs code debugger is not recognizing any breakpoints, nor is it logging any console.log messages.  The web inspector is working, but the vs code debugger is not.
I've tried editing launch.json and tasks.json.  I am using the Office Add-ins Development Kit to create a simple add-in to get this setup.  I have installed the Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code as well.
this is my launch.json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Chromium)",
      "type": "msedge",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9222, // Default debugging port for Edge
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "trace": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Excel Desktop (Edge Legacy)",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "url": "https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html?_host_Info=Excel$Mac$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
      "port": 9222, // Default debugging port for Chrome
      "timeout": 600000,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "preLaunchTask": "Debug: Excel Desktop",
      "postDebugTask": "Stop Debug",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "trace": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}

below is what I am trying to debug.  It is from the example provided by Microsoft when learning office add-ins.
/*
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license.
 * See LICENSE in the project root for license information.
 */

/* global console, document, Excel, Office */

Office.onReady((info) => {
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
    document.getElementById("sideload-msg").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app-body").style.display = "flex";
    document.getElementById("run").onclick = run;
  }
});

export async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      /**
       * Insert your Excel code here
       */
      const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

      // Read the range address
      range.load("address");

      // Update the fill color
      range.format.fill.color = "yellow";
      console.log("hi");

      await context.sync();
      console.log(`The range address was ${range.address}.`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}


Can you share a [mre] of code you are trying to debug?  (Please add it to your question using [edit])

"...provided by Microsoft when learning office add-ins."  Why do you not (also) share a link to that provider?

I think the info you are searching for is here: Debug add-ins using developer tools in Microsoft Edge

Thank you for your help with this.  I'm not sure how to include the link to the provider.  I used the office add-in development kit extension in vs code to create this sample.

when I look at the personality menu for the add-in that runs (but won't debug), it says this.  Source: Store
Runtime: Safari WebKit
Version: 3.0.0.0.  Could this be a reason why I cannot debug?

It sounds like you are working on a Mac. Are you familiar with Debug Office Add-ins on a Mac?

Yes, that is correct.  I am familiar with that link, and I should clarify.  I was able to debug via the safari web inspector.  I am hoping to be able to debug as I do on my windows machine within vs code.  Is this not possible with a mac?  Thank you for your help with this.
